# 'I am having something done' means 'I am arranging somebody else to do sth' or 'somebody else is doing something for you'?

Tags: passive-voice

I'm learning the structure 'have + obj + past participle' from a grammar book. The book gives a example here:

> We are having the house painted at the moment.

I know the structure means 'arrange somebody else to do something for us'. But I wonder in this sentence which action is continuous. So the sentence should be explained as 'I am arranging somebody else to paint my house at the moment', for example when I'm phoning somebody, or 'Somebody is painting my house at the moment'. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *Someone is painting the house at the moment, because we arranged for them to do it.*

The continuous action is the painting.